# Is it possible to edit an intent more than 7 times?

Tags: amazon-lex

The only way I found to edit an intent in Amazon Lex is by selecting *Latest* in the drop down menu next to the intent name. Then, every time I click *Build*, the version number increases. When it reaches the version 7, the *Latest* option disappears and I am not able to edit the intent anymore. Does it mean I can only edit an intent 7 times? Or is there any other way to edit intents?

[image: Edit intent dorp down menu]

Thx

Comment: Well, according to [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gl-limits.html), the maximum number of versions you can publish is 100.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully updated beyond 7 versions. If you are still seeing this behavior, it may be appropriate to file a bug report.

Are you positive you are saving changes made to your intent, before you attempt to build a new version? Sometimes with the UI it is tricky to know if you have made changes. For example, when adding a slot, you need to click on the "+" button for the new slot to be registered as a change for when you save the intent.